Why was Pa's character replaced with Drummer in The Expanse?
When The Expanse was reimagined as a TV/streaming series the majority of scenes that originally featured the character Michio Pa were re-written to feature Carmina Drummer instead.
In many cases this was a straight character swap with Drummer occupying an effectively identical part in the wider storyline to Pa, or performing an equivalent function in the story but with some modifications in line with the reimagined continuity.
As Drummer was essentially a background character up until the seventh book, when she became a member of the regular cast, the writers effectively renamed Pa to Drummer for most of the story. Rather than creating a new composite character with the attributes of both.
Pa still exists as a secondary/background character, though with little of her original involvement in the story.
Was any explanation or rational ever provided to explain why Drummer was elevated to the main cast, while Pa was relegated to an incidental background character, with most of here scenes being given to Drummer?
For example was it mentioned in a directory commentary, or explained in behind the scenes documentary. Is there any record of the crew/cast being asked about this during an interview or a convention panel event?
Has this been commented upon by the team behind the original novels?

"Rather than a more traditional merging of two characters or the creation of a composite character" - There you have it, a salary saved!

That doesn't really answer the question. Drummer was a relatively low level character with few appearances, Pa was one of the main characters from the second book onwards. Why merge Pa with Drummer, rather than Drummer with Pa? I'm interested to know if there was a reason for doing it this way around, rather than the other way.

@AaarghZombies - Probably because they had no idea if they'd get a second series. No point worrying about things that happen x seasons down the line..

I've heard they expanded Drummers role because of the popularity of the character/actress in early episodes. Don't have a definitive source for that though

@Dave Smith, I'm not sure that's the case. When they reimagined the Expanse for TV they took several female characters from later on in the franchise and put them in the first few episodes. long before they ever appeared in the books. Bobbie, Avalarala, Anna Volovodov and Drummer were the most prominent. They chose them early on to be brought forward. Based on this, it looks like the chose Drummer to take over from Pa right from the get go. The other three were all big characters in the book with their own unique story, but Drummer was a background character.

@Valorum, so why change Drummer\Pa at all and not just put them in as in the original material?

@AaarghZombies - Every character with a line gets residual payments. Fewer characters equals less money and also fewer people that audiences need to keep track of.

@Valorum, I'm still not sure how any of this explains why Drummer was the character that was kept, when it required the biggest number of changes to the show.

You've stumbled on a reasonable explanation yourself in the comments. Specifically:

Why merge Pa with Drummer, rather than Drummer with Pa?  I'm interested to know if there was a reason for doing it this way around, rather than the other way.
When they reimagined the Expanse for TV they took several female characters from later on in the franchise and put them in the first few episodes. long before they ever appeared in the books. Bobbie, Avalarala, Anna Volovodov and Drummer were the most prominent. They chose them early on to be brought forward.

If you assume that a merging of the characters is reasonable (which your first comment very much does seem to agree with), then the remaining question is who gets merged into who.
Pointing out a tendency for the show to "pull up" some female roles to the earlier seasons - whatever the reason may have been, presumably some kind of gender diversity - would also suggest why the writers would have favored Drummer surviving the merge instead of Pa.


so why change Drummer\Pa at all and not just put them in as in the original material?

Let's sidestep the trivial "less casting cost" answer, even though it's probably one of the main ones. There's two different points I want to explore here.
1 - Cast size should not grow too large
In The Lion King 3, Timon was originally slated to have a mother, father, and uncle Max. However, it was decided to remove the father and merge his role into the character of Timon's mother. The reason for this being that learning too many characters/faces negatively impacts the experience for an audience. Since Timon's mom and dad performed the exact same narrative role (that of a supportive parent who doesn't quite understand their child but loves and supports them anyway), there was little purpose to having two faces to remember.
Sure, The Lion King didn't have that big of a cast, but because it was targeted to kids, the need to keep the cast size down was stronger. While targeted at adults, The Expanse deals with a very (pun not intended) expansive cast already, with many different roles that support the narrative in different ways.
It is very reasonable for the showrunners to want to trim the fat on excessive cast members who don't need to individually exist in order to support the narrative. Drummer and Pa perform very similar roles and were relatively ripe for merging.
As a counterexample of a merge that couldn't happen: Fred Johnson and Anderson Dawes. They start off firmly in the same camp, both acting as Belter leaders in their own way. However, as the story progresses, the Belter faction splits off into its diplomatic half (Fred) and its persistently extremist half (Dawes). You need two faces here, because you need them to diverge at some point.
2 - Books and stories work very differently for readers and viewers, respectively. The visual nature of a medium changes the rules.
In a book, having two characters doesn't really change much in terms of how the narrative is conveyed to you. Unless you go through the effort of really making them speak differently and spelling things differently between the characters, it's only going to be their name that matters.
In a visual format, the whole face changes, and you cannot rely on a narrator to constantly remind the viewer who this face is. These people are going to enter the scene, not be announced explicitly, and it's expected that the viewer knows who they are so they can pick up their ongoing narrative.
In a book, a narrator is required to point out anything non-verbal that is happening. This allows for exposition in a way that shows cannot generally get away with. This is why the As You Know trope has become prevalent in visual mediums more than written ones.
Compare the show version:

"Shall we have this dance, Eleanor?"
"Robert, I am betrothed to your brother! My father, the king of Elbonia, will not be pleased to see us dancing at the ball. No!"

To the book version:

Robert turned to Eleanor. "Shall we have this dance?" Eleanor felt conflicted. Her father would not be pleased to see the princess of Elbonia dancing with her betrothed's brother at the ball.

A narrator has the implicit role of introducing exposition. In a visual medium, the characters themselves are responsible for introducing this exposition, which feels out of place in a conversation between two characters.
It's not just about exposition, it's also about ongoing things. For example, in A Song Of Ice And Fire, Tyrion's face is horribly disfigured after the battle of King's Landing, to the point of losing his nose. In Game of Thrones (the show), Tyrion's wound soon heals and is nothing more than a superficial scar on his face. Viewers complained about this change.
The reality is that in the book, the disfigurement would only matter at times where the book explicitly brought it up. At all other times, Tyrion's interaction in a scene wouldn't change because of his disfigurement.
This would not be the case for the show. Tyrion's face would constantly be on the screen, for every line he would speak. His voice would be altered based on not having a nose. It would be a constant distraction even in scenes that feature Tyrion but aren't intended to focus on his disfigurement. It would also hamper the actor's ability to convey emotion on his face; which happens non-verbally in a show, but in a book is something that the narrator can point out.
The key takeaway here is that the rules between written mediums and visual mediums are different, and you can't always transplant a book detail to a show detail without losing narrative impact/efficiency/potency.
Furthermore, because of the existence of visual implications in a visual format, it can be harder to find the right actor to cast based on exactly what you want the character to be able to do. You might want to hire Anthony Hopkins because the character he's going to play is an older charismatic serial killer, but it's not going to be convincing when you have him parkour up the side of a parking garage.
In a written medium, you're not restricted by the "premade" actors that you could cast for the role. You build your own character, including any description of their looks, in order to perfectly tailor it to what you need it to be.
In conclusion, there are plenty of reasons why such a merge would be considered. It reduces the cast size and casting costs, it streamlines the narrative for a more non-intrusive visual exposition, it removes casting restrictions when a character combines traits that aren't easily found in an actor, and it can help avoid visual distractions that would otherwise plague scenes with the actor in it.
The argument that it could've been done because that's what they did in the book holds no water, because different mediums have different challenges as to how they convey a narrative and its exposition. Different challenges can lead to different decisions needing to be made.

Seems possible also that if casting for one character went particularly well, they might lean into that and fold another character into the one with the great actor. That may or may not apply in this case, but as part of the adaptation process in general, I feel like it’s been done that way.

@Flater It's unlikely to be due to diversity reasons. Drummer and Pa were bother strong female minority characters, but Pa was also bisexual. So she was the more diverse character. It seems odd to keep a side character like Drummer at the expense of more diverse main character.

@Flater, no offense, but I'm looking for something from the people behind the book or the TV series rather than an exploration of the possibilities by fans.

@AaarghZombies Word of God is admissible as an answer but mandating it from the question out means you're either asking for a direct Word of God or for people to do your googling for you; both of which is off-topic.

@Flater, I'm asking people not to post guesses. It need to be from a verifiable source, and asking for a verifiable source isn't off topic. For example, interviews with the crew or cast are often featured alongside series on Amazon Prime. It's not unreasonable to think that someone may be aware of something that I missed.

@AaarghZombies: You're looking for a biased source of information. No one is going to publicize e.g. that they wanted to suppress the casting cost, if that were the reason. You're blindly assuming that the reason for this decision is something that will be openly discussed and revealed.

@Flater, I'm asking for an accurate source of information, not fan speculation on possible motivations. Hence why I mentioned things like behind the scenes documentaries. I mentioned that Pa was bisexual, and you're interpreting that as me asking why an LGBTQI+ character was censored out of the show. I'm not. I'm asking why Pa was merged with Drummer, and not the other way around as Pa this would require the biggest number re-writes. It seems more effort. Please don't read between the lines. My question is literal.

Might be as simple as the sound of the name
If you're going to merge two characters from a book into a single character in the adaptation, you really have the opportunity to select whichever name you want for the composite character. The name "Drummer" is stronger sounding than the name "Pa," and the composite character is a strong character. Further, the word "Pa" evokes an antiquated/colloquial way of referring to one's father. In this sense, it's kind of silly sounding and might even invite comparisons to "Pa" from Little House on the Prairie.
